# No output while using Nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

When I tried to write a sample 'nomenclature' page , I get no output text and I get just a blank page with a page number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{The next list describes several symbols that will be later used within the body of the document}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

\printnomenclature
\end{document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you use the document build sequence: (pdf)latex makeindex (pdf)latex? See, for example, [Using package nomencl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27824).

Comment: Instructions for are in the package [documentation](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf) -- makeindex is needed before you will see a result.   If you just want to make a nomenclature list with all this fuss, you can define an environment as discussed in this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397245/nomenclature-indentation).